# data.table: removing ALL rows after a condition is met

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I've read many threads here about subsetting data, but I haven't found anything that answers my specific question about subsetting a time series dataset.

What I would like to do is find the rows that meet a condition, and then delete the first row that meets the condition, and all rows after it (regardless of whether they meet the condition or not).

An example dataset:

```
AnimalID  Latitude  Longitude  Speed  Date  
99B       50.86190  -129.0875  5.6    2015-05-14 21:26:00 
99B       50.86170  -129.0875  0.6    2015-05-14 21:32:00
99B       50.86150  -129.0810  0.5    2015-05-14 21:33:00
99B       50.86140  -129.0800  0.3    2015-05-14 21:40:00
```

To find the rows that meet the condition, I have the code
`DT[Speed < 0.8 & Date > as.POSIXct("2015-05-14 21:30:00"), by=AnimalID]`
However, I have no idea how to delete the rows.

Many thanks

Comment: DO you have `AnimalID` as grouping variable?

Comment: Try using dput to post your example so others can try it out, and add the data.table tag if you think it's relevant. No need to write "tags" into the title.

Comment: `DT[1:which(Speed < 0.8 & Date > as.POSIXct("2015-05-14 21:30:00")[1]]` may work if grouping is not an issue.

Comment: @lmo They need to delete the obs meeting the criterion as well.

Comment: @Frank OK `DT[1:(which(Speed < 0.8 & Date > as.POSIXct("2015-05-14 21:30:00")[1]-1)]` slight alteration.

Comment: @lmo Not quite robust, still. What happens when the which() returns 1 and you have 1:0?

Comment: @Frank double-robustified: `DT[1:(max(which(Speed < 0.8 & Date > as.POSIXct("2015-05-14 21:30:00")[1])-1, 1, na.rm=T))]` to both `which(...)[1]` returning 1 and returning empty.

Comment: @lmo This is fun. I'm still skeptical of any approach like `1:x` since we may want to drop all rows. Let's take it to the R chat room if you want to discuss further.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
require(data.table)

dt = data.table(
  AnimalID = rep('99B', 4),
  Latitude = c(50.86190,50.86170,50.86150,50.86140),
  Longitude = c(-129.0875,-129.0875,-129.0810,-129.0800),
  Speed = c(5.6,0.6,0.5,0.3),
  Date = as.POSIXct(c('2015-05-14 21:26:00', '2015-05-14 21:32:00', '2015-05-14 21:33:00', '2015-05-14 21:40:00')))

dt[, cond := Speed < 0.8 & Date > as.POSIXct("2015-05-14 21:30:00")]
dt[, cond_cumsum := cumsum(cond)] # everything > 0 follows a row that met the condition
dt_sub = dt[cond_cumsum == 0]
```

Comment: I tried this on a subset of my data and it worked beautifully, now I need to scale it up. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index for the first item in DF meeting the condition using `which`:

```
index <- which(DT$Speed < 0.8 & DT$Date > as.POSIXct("2015-05-14 21:30:00"))[1]
```

or to be safe:

```
index <- min(which(DT$Speed < 0.8 & DT$Date > as.POSIXct("2015-05-14 21:30:00")))
```

you can then delete the range of rows in the data set starting from index to the last row:

```
DT <- DT[-(index:nrow(DT))]
```

Comment: Items in `which` are always ordered. Both ways are unsafe with respect to `which` returning an empty vector.

Comment: @Frank under what circumstances would `which` return an empty vector aside from the conditions not being met?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. That's the only circumstance I might be worried about. I'm not sure what circumstances you had in mind when taking the min, but as far as I know, it won't do anything differently so long as the condition is met somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I suspected that `which` always returns an ordered vector. I wasn't sure whether there was a situation where this wouldn't be true so `min` could account for that.